# "Permission Denied" using RCS commands (ci and co) as root

Tags: linux, permissions, revision-control, ci

I've su'd into our company server as the root user (verified with id, I show up as user 0). I'm trying to use the Revision Control System to check in and check out files, but even as root, I'm getting "Permission Denied" when I try to run ci on the files in question (nothing is currently checked out).

I ran a quick controlled test to assure that this wasn't an issue with the files themselves. I made a fresh new directory and created a testfile.txt and an RCS directory within it. Upon attempting to ci the new file, I am still getting "Permission Denied". I have found no information on this issue online. What's going on? I'm newer to systems administration and Linux, so if there's any additional information you need me to provide to get to the bottom of this, please let me know. [shell output of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmKqE.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: either ci (which seems to be a script file) doesn't have exec permissions or shebang is wrong. Can you check that?

Comment: I checked the permissions, and it indeed didn't have execute permissions set! ci and co were symbolic links to the rcs file, so giving that execute permissions worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "permission denied" you're getting is not because of the `ci` command *arguments* but because of the `ci` file itself.

Either it lacks proper execution rights (even in root mode, may require a `chmod a+x ci`), or it has a shebang which doesn't exist (check first line of the script if it's a script)

In both cases, it's not considered as an executable by the system and that's where "permission denied" comes from.